# Cyanogen OS 14 for OnePlus One?

Tags: oneplus-one, 7.0-nougat, cyanogen-os

Will there a Cyanogen OS 14? And if so will it be available for the OnePlus One?

Comment: Why not ask at Cyanogen? They are much more likely able to tell you. We are not, and CM14 AFAIK isn't even released at all.

Comment: Ah. Okay. I hear ya

Comment: @Izzy Just a heads-up that CM14.1 has been out officially for a lil while. No Xposed to accompany though.

Comment: To OP: it usually takes months for Cyngn to add in and test their proprietary stuff before releasing, so just wait patiently.

Comment: Yeah. I know. Planning to to root soon. Now tell me how this is off topic? @Izzy